# Play videos via 3rd party library or as animation in libGDX?

Tags: libgdx, animation, video

I want to add an animated splash screen to my desktop game, which I develop using libGDX. Now I see there is no native support for videos in libGDX, so I guess I have two options:

1. Include a 3rd party framework for video playback (like the Java
   media framework); or
2. Save the video as a series of PNG images and
   play them as a libGDX animation.

Since the splash screen video is not very long, maybe 5 seconds or so, I tend to the libGDX animation option. However, the video would be full screen, so rather large images, and I am not sure whether an animation would really be the best option in that case.

Does anyone of you guys have some experience with (full screen) video playback under libGDX on the desktop?

Comment: Animations don't necessarily have to be the full blown cell method. You could split the assets and distribute them the way you would in game sprites and animate them programatically. However, I would be interested in someone providing an example of video integration.